# HTML5 Animate line to draw musical note symbol

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I want to create a canvas, and draw a line that makes turns and draw a musical note (a Sol Key actually) then goes off on the right side of the canvas.

I have searched and found a script that draw a line - but so far the only thing it does is to draw a line. Every attempt to modify it in order to create curves and figures went horribly wrong.

The code I have:

```js
var canvas = $("#paper")[0];
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var h = canvas.height;

var startX = 10;
var startY = h/2;
var endX = 500;
var endY = h/2;
var amount = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  amount += 0.002; // change to alter duration
  if (amount > 1) amount = 1;
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  c.strokeStyle = "black";
  c.moveTo(startX, startY);
  c.lineTo(startX + (endX - startX) * amount, startY + (endY - startY) * amount);
  c.stroke();
}, 10);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="paper" width="800" height="600" border="1"></canvas>
```

Comment: I just want to point out, animating the canvas with setInterval or setTimeout is not the proper way to do it. Frames will get drawn with imprecise delta times which leads to poor performance. [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) is the way to go. Using a external script such as [Canvas.js](https://github.com/GustavGenberg/handy-front-end#canvasjs) makes that alot easier.

Comment: And the way im thinking of doing it is by getting the sol key as a svg path, parse it and then do interpolation to really make it animated when drawing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a pretty whide question because there is a lot of ways to do it. In the example below at JSFiddle I used an external Canvas helper to make the code easier to read.

I did not use interpolation due to no need for it, so the animating is pretty simple.

How its animating the sol:

- Get the SVG path of the sol
- Parse it and make it easier readable
- Start animating the first path item - wait - and go to the next one
- And after a few seconds you have your sol!

Using

```
const canvas = new Canvas(); // Canvas.js
```

The draw loop and the update loop are pretty obvious...

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y0g2q33g/

**Note** The code in this fiddle is not optimized at all :)